# How to add a table to AWS DynamoDB Table group using AWS SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I need to create dynamoDB tables then group them based on Dev, Stage and Production. I Found an option in the AWS console to create a Table group and we can add the tables to the group. but I need to add tables to a particular group using AWS SDK, I checked AWS DynamoDB SDK Class list I didn't find any option.

Answer (score 1):

The groups are created and managed using [AWS Resource Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/userguide/welcome.html). To explicitly add table to a given group you have to use [groupResources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ResourceGroups.html#groupResources-property) SDK method.